# CSS to give float inside container priority

Tags: css, css-float

`float:left` behaves differently in chrome and ie7 as shown by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grastveit/rhKsu/) and ascii-art below:

IE7 does,

```
<-width->
Col1 Col2
text # #
     # #
     # #
```

instead of

```
<-width->
Col1
text
col2
# # # # #
#
```

Is there a way to get the ie7-behaviour in all browsers?

In other words not stack col1 and col2 unless the page is very narrow. The goal is to have a "superfluid" two-column layout where col1 fits its content and col2 uses the remaining width of the window and wraps its content or is shown below col1 if it cannot fit beside it.

Rewritten to be more precise after feedback in answer and comments.

Comment: I have looked at this fiddle and reread this question, but have a really hard time figuring out what you're asking. Is there a reason you're using `<br />` and `<table>` to create this layout? Making that layout in ascii art #1 is easy enough, but the question is confusing.  Have you looked at the CSS `clear` property?

Comment: Ok, I simplified the fiddle to only show the problem. The ´table´ was there to show the wanted behaviuour but i guess it caused confusion instead.

Comment: I'm only confused because this looks extremely trivial to do. Is [this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/LpkQX/25/)? If not, please explain why.

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting a specific width for the columns. The width of column1 should be determined by the content. Column2 should fill the rest of the wrapper-width (window). Nice touch with backgrounds.

Comment: Since I'm already using jQuery I'll use this workaround for now `$('#col2').width($('#wrapper').width() - $('#col2').prev().width());`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still having trouble understanding what you're after and what the problem is. I'm going to just post an answer and you can shoot down the ideas as we go.

**Attempt 1:**

You need to set a width on at least one of the columns.

Try this and tell me what's wrong with it. http://jsfiddle.net/LpkQX/27/

**Attempt 2:**

Float the right column *inside* the left column. Now column1 is just a wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpkQX/28/

Comment: Well, it shows exactly as it should. The problem is the fixed width. I think setting width should not be necessary since IE behaves as required. Please try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Grastveit/rhKsu/) simplified example in ie to see.

Comment: Seeing your updated simplified fiddle, this looks exactly the same in FF4, Chrome 10, and IE8. When asking about IE, always specify version because each one is quite different. However, I think I see what you are referring to now in IE6 and 7 - but changing the text makes it render the way you want in other browsers so I'm failing to see how this is really a way you want to structure a design.

Comment: IE7 yes, sorry for not specifying it. What do you mean by changing the text makes it reander the way I want? Thanks for the effort in answering, I think think I will update the question based on this if it not against protocol.